# How to save a string of 1's and 0's as binary to a binary file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bitstream

I am currently trying to complete a project for school that involves reading an audio 'wav' file, using a golomb encoder to encode the samples, writing the result to a binary file, reading that binary file on another script and decoding it using the golomb decoder.
The assignment guide suggests I develop a BitStream class that can read and write a single bit and read and write n bits.
I have done the golomb encoder and decoder and it seems to be working well. However, I am having trouble with the BitStream part. I have tried searching for existing classes online but as I am fairly new to programming, they all seem super complicated to work with. My golomb coder returns a string of 1's and 0's and the decoder works with a similar string as input.
Another questions I have are: When I am done writing the binary files, how do I know where each sample code starts and ends? How do I pass the sampling frequency to the decoder? How do I know where the left and right channels of the audio sample begin and end? How do I encode the M parameter of the golomb encoder of each separate sample?
I am supposed to do this in Python by the way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you format this a bit better, it is difficult to read. Could you share the relevant code? See [mcve]. Also, this seems quite broad.

Comment: I suggest you look at `open()` using the `b` flag. I also suggest that you rethink how you implement the encoder and decoder to work directly on bytes instead of on a string of 0's and 1's.

Comment: [Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) ... Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service.   You should invest some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer for solving your problem.

Comment: This is both unclear and too broad. Please focus on a single issue, and provide the relevant code (instead of just alluding to the code).

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the binary, you shouldn't have to worry about where the audio starts, etc, the libraries should do that for you. To save a string with bitstring you can do them all at once, save to a string then run the BitStream like:

```
BitStream(bin='101010101').tofile(filename)
```

Your question has a few moving parts, but if your string of one zeroes is working with golomb, the binary you read back from BitString should work as is.

One tip i have, i use this for huffman encoders too. If the binary strings you generate with the encode you have ever start with '0000's Then always prepend a '1' to the binary string before write, and strip the prepended '1' on read. This keeps you from having to store an external data about the save of the binary buffer, since binary has to be stored with a leading 1